# Dependence of product of matrix and a vector, on the rank of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the significance of the rank of a matrix, say $A$, when I am multiplying a vector, say $x$, by $A$?

In other words, let $x$ be a column vector of suitable dimension and let $rank (A)=m$. What is the nature of the product $Ax$ as a function of $m$ ?

Comment: It's not clear what kind of answer you're looking for here.  A matrix product works the same way, no matter what the ranks of the matrices involved happen to be.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could elaborate on what kind of difference you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication of a matrix with a vector is a linear transformation of the vector. To give meaning to this linear transformation, look into the context in which the operation is done.